# Testing QML based app with pytest in python

Tags: python, qt, qml, pytest, pyside2

I would like to test my QML frontend code along with my Python backend code(using PySide2) with Pytest preferably, and be able to send `keyClicks`, `MouseClicks` and `signals` just like [pytest-qt](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt) plugin does. I have already checked out [pytest-qml](https://github.com/jgirardet/pytest-qml), but the test code is written via QML, and then only ran via via pytest, but I would like to send events and such from python itself, not QML

Basically, having the python code as such:

```python
"""
Slots, Signals, context class etc etc...
"""

app = QGuiApplication([])
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile("main.qml"))
app.exec_()
```

and a simple `main.qml` file, as such,

```qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15


ApplicationWindow {
    id: mywin
    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
    visible: true
    FileDialog {
            id: openDialog
            title: "mydialog"
            onAccepted: {
            }
        }
    Button {
        objectName: "mybtn"
        width: 200
        height: 200
        id: btn
        text: "hello"
        onClicked: {
            openDialog.open()
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do (pseudo-code)something like

```python
def test_file_open():
    #Grab QQuickItem(btn)
    #Send mouse event to click btn
    #Send string to file dialog
    # assert string sent ==  string selected
```

The `pytest-qt` plugin would work, but functions take `QWidget` and QML deals with `QQuickItems`, which as far as I know doesnt deal with QWidgets.

Is it even possible, or my only option to test my app slots etc is via the `pytest-qml` ? Perhaps its the easiest way, but perhaps there are other options :)

Edit:

If you use `import Qt.labs.platform 1.1` instead of the `import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3`, and force QML to *not* use native dialog, then just change

```
    # assert myfiledialog.property("fileUrl").toLocalFile() == filename  # uses QDialog
    assert myfiledialog.property("currentFile").toLocalFile() == filename # using QLabs Dialog
```

And then using the rest of the code from accepted answer it will work, so apparently its very important that it does not use a native dialog.

If anyone else in the future knows how to make it work with native dialog and using `QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3` as the original question presented, it would be nice :). But this is still nice to test overall!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same API since pytest-qt is based on QtTest. Obviously you must understand the structure of the application, for example that the FileDialog is just a QObject that only manages a QWindow that has the dialog, in addition to managing the positions of the items with respect to the windows.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def build_engine():
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIR / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
    engine.load(url)
    return engine


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication([])
    engine = build_engine()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mywin

    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
    visible: true

    FileDialog {
        id: openDialog

        objectName: "myfiledialog"
        title: "mydialog"
        onAccepted: {
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: btn

        objectName: "mybtn"
        width: 200
        height: 200
        text: "hello"
        onClicked: {
            openDialog.open();
        }
    }

}
```

```py
import os

from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QObject, Qt, QPointF
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickItem
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

import pytest

from app import build_engine


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def qapp():
    QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("qapp")
    QCoreApplication.setOrganizationDomain("qapp.com")
    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_DontUseNativeDialogs)
    yield QApplication([])


def test_app(tmp_path, qtbot):
    engine = build_engine()

    assert QCoreApplication.testAttribute(Qt.AA_DontUseNativeDialogs)
    
    with qtbot.wait_signal(engine.objectCreated, raising=False):
        assert len(engine.rootObjects()) == 1
    root_object = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    root_item = root_object.contentItem()

    mybtn = root_object.findChild(QQuickItem, "mybtn")
    assert mybtn is not None

    center = QPointF(mybtn.width(), mybtn.height()) / 2
    qtbot.mouseClick(
        mybtn.window(),
        Qt.LeftButton,
        pos=root_item.mapFromItem(mybtn, center).toPoint(),
    )
    qtbot.wait(1000)
    qfiledialog = None
    for window in QGuiApplication.topLevelWindows():
        if window is not root_object:
            qfiledialog = window
    assert qfiledialog is not None, QGuiApplication.topLevelWindows()

    file = tmp_path / "foo.txt"
    file.touch()
    filename = os.fspath(file)

    for letter in filename:
        qtbot.keyClick(qfiledialog, letter, delay=100)

    qtbot.wait(1000)

    qtbot.keyClick(qfiledialog, Qt.Key_Return)

    qtbot.wait(1000)

    myfiledialog = root_object.findChild(QObject, "myfiledialog")
    assert myfiledialog is not None

    assert myfiledialog.property("fileUrl").toLocalFile() == filename
```

Note: The test may fail if the filedialog uses the native window, you could use tools like pyinput but a simpler option is to use virtualenv.

Comment: First of all thanks for the help! However, it breaks in `assert qfiledialog is not None` because `window.objectName()` always returns `None`, therefore it never gets assigned to the window.

Comment: @dmatos2012 1. objectName() must not return None but a string, and by default it must be an empty string. How have you verified that it returns None?

Comment: @dmatos2012 try with my update

Comment: I run it via pytest, and I get the following
`>       assert qfiledialog is not None
E       assert None is not None` . Then 
`----------------------------- Captured Qt messages -----------------------------
QtWarningMsg: Model size of -181 is less than 0
QtWarningMsg: Model size of -20 is less than 0
----------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------

(python3:109395): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:35:01.122: gtk_image_set_from_gicon: assertion 'GTK_IS_IMAGE (image)' failed
==short test summary info ============
FAILED est_app - assert None is not None`

Comment: And I said about `window.objectName()` because when i printed it, its always an empty string, therefore its always `qfiledialog = None`, which fails on the assert above.

Comment: @dmatos2012 Probably your app is using the native dialog and not the Qt one, to debug change `assert qfiledialog is not None` to `assert qfiledialog is not None, [(window.metaObject().className(), window.objectName()) for window in QGuiApplication.topLevelWindows()]`

Comment: Im using `PySide2/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml` because i can see it in the warnings. 

Output of that list comprehension is, `[('ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_1', '')]`. So it looks like that `FileDialog` window is not considered a topLevelWindow? Please let me know if you want other debugging information, or if I have to change to native dialog. Thank you so much still for your help. Its further than I have ever reached so far!

Comment: @dmatos2012 What happens is that the application is using the native window where my logic fails, to avoid that I recommend using a virtualenv, which is a more controlled environment.

Comment: Using virtualenv has nothing to do with it, as i am using a virtualenv, and it doesnt make a difference. I tweaked a bit more and noticed that there is something with QML that is beyond me that still uses native Dialog(see my edit), but if I change dialog to `qtlabs.platform` with your code to force non-native dialog, then your code works. I will mark as correct since it helped me a ton even though it does not work for native dialogs, and with `qtquick.dialogs` which is what i wanted to use. But thanks anyways, it helped a ton. Thanks!